# Disable href after clicking (ajax, js)

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
$('#checkout').click(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'index.php?route=payment/quatro/confirm',
        success: function() {
            location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';
        }       
    });
});
```

What is the good way to disable this `<a href>` link button after clicking on it? I tried  `$('#checkout').disabled` function, but the click function is still working.

Comment: 1 year 1 month is long enough to learn Markdown formatting, I think!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of your click handler I would add a call to `unbind` to remove the click handler going forward

```
$('#checkout').unbind("click");
```

So the full code would be:

```
$('#checkout').click(function() {
    $('#checkout').unbind("click");
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'index.php?route=payment/quatro/confirm',
        success: function() {
            location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';
        }       
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `return false;` at the end of your click event, that should prevent the link from going anywhere.

```
$('#checkout').click(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'index.php?route=payment/quatro/confirm',
        success: function() {
            location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';
        }       
    });

    return false;
});
```