# Partial View is loaded only after an ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have converted from using IE7 to IE9 and unfortunately my partial view is returned and overwrites the entire page with the partial view.

Doing an on Click of a button in html, I call up a

In javascript:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $('form').attr('action'),
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (response) {
                alert('Pass'); // This will be hit
            },
            error: function (errorObj) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
```

This then goes to the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Index model)
    {
    return NewFeature(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewFeature(Index model)
    {
        return PartialView("_feature", model);
    }
```

Any idea what it could be?

Comment: 1) if the ajax is triggered by a link click or form submit, make sure you [e.g. cancel the action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370286/disable-href-after-clicking-ajax-js) 2) Make sure you don't have `_layout.cshtml` in your partial.

Answer (score 0):

So long as it is not a submit button there is no need to prevent the default behavior. If it is a submit button, you then need to override the base action by returning false. i.e.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return myFunction()" />

function myFunction()
{
    DoWork();
    return false;
}
```

Since you are returning a partial and have confirmed that the alert is being hit, the answer should be as simple as:

```
success: function (response) {
            $("#DivIdToUpdate").html(response);
        }
```

Another thing to note is that the type is probably supposed to be json not text, but I can't see the rest of your code. Additionally it seems that on your controller you are calling the functions incorrectly. Try changing this as well.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Index model)
{
    return this.RedirectToAction("NewFeature", new { model = model });
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult NewFeature(Index model)
{
    return this.PartialView("_feature", model);
}
```

This code is following the post -> redirect -> get pattern and will make two requests, one to do work and another to get the fresh data. This will cause the ModelState to refresh and freshly load all the data you need. The javascript ajax post will receive the ActionResult from the controller as compiled cshtml, so by calling the code above, the html will be rendered inside of whichever element you prefer.

Also,

```
url: $('form').attr('action'),
```

Can easily translate into:

```
url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/Index")',
```